# visual studio 2013 - windows phone development logging without debugging

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone

Is it possible to log my Windows Phone without debugging it?

I am porting a phonegap cordova app and need to see the log (in the output view coming from my function console.log); 
but if I deploy my app using the device raw sometimes it starts debugging C# code (entering in some exception)  which I dont want to happen.

If I just deploy the app, it does not get logs.

How to get rid of C# debugging?

Comment: Can you not filter out the C# exceptions out of the log? There are some pretty easily defined patterns.

Comment: I would also love to know how to do this..
In iOS and Android you can just run the app without debugging and you will see logs in xcode and eclipse respectively. If some one knows this it would be great.

Comment: @Ashishail, there is no way to do that in VS. There is a tool for getting a log file called powertool (http://wptools.codeplex.com/) but it does not behave the same as logcat.

Comment: Yes I know about log files. but it is a real shame that you cannot view phone logs on the fly. What if I want to run app on two phone and debug them.. so stupid.